# Handling RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR on the Java side using BC4J

Tags: java, oracle, error-handling, oracle-adf, bc4j

How can I handle the error thrown from the database side with RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR at the Java side.

I am using the BC4J framework and in that a `ViewObject` is used to pass data to the database, so the code from where I am setting data doesn't throw `SqlException` hence I can not put it in a `try..catch`.

**UPDATE**

How can we handle `SQLException` getting raised from somewhere else. We cant put `try catch` block for it as its a checked exception and will compile time error.

Comment: Give description what exactly try to do

Comment: What do you mean? You'll get an `SQLException` just like any predefined exception, it'll just have your designated error code and message. Are you expecting it to behave differently, or you want to know how to handle any exception?

Comment: @AlexPoole Yes thats true, but the case is I am using BC4J framework and in that ViewObject is used to pass data to database, so the code from where I am setting data doesn't throw `SqlException` hence I can not put it in `try..catch`.

Comment: Add `BC4J` tag by editing your question..

Comment: You don't think it would have been useful to mention that in the question? And show your code where you're calling the procedure, and where it needs to handle the exception? And show what happens now when you get the exception?

Comment: I think this question should be closed. As its very hard to explain to all of you.

Comment: No @eatSleepCode, you just left out almost all information related to your question. If you'd actually included all the information at the beginning then it would be fine. There's no need to close the question, just to add the relevant information.

Comment: @Ben I have also put some update over this.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you raise error like:

```
raise_application_error(-2222, 'err message for -2222 error');
```

In `JDBC` invocation of this stored procedure, inside `catch`:

```
try {

//invoke stored-procedure

}catch(SQLException e) {
if(e.getErrorCode()==-2222) {
//handle error here, or convert to some specific error and use e.getMessage()
}
}
```

**EDIT:**

I haven't used `BC4J` but its `JboException` too have `String getErrorCode()`, you can try playing around this..

Comment: Yes correct, but the case is I am using BC4J framework and in that ViewObject is used to pass data to database, so the code from where I am setting data doesn't throw `SqlException` hence I can not put it in `try..catch`.